# @Given symbol not found though dependencies are added

Tags: cucumber

[image]

Though I have added cucumber dependencies but @Given, @When etc annotations are not resolved.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-junit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.6</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the classes for @Given and @When:

```
import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;
import cucumber.api.java.en.When;
```

and any other you might use:

```
import cucumber.api.java.en.And;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Then;
```

Currently, you have only imported:

```
import cucumber.api.PendingException
```

which is why the following has resolved in your example above:

```
public void user_login_into_application_with_username_and_password
    throw new PendingException()
```